# Is developing C# with Xcode still available?

Tags: c#, xcode

I'm looking for the way to develop a C# project with Xcode, and I found only this website. [ https://code.google.com/archive/p/cocoa-sharp-dev/wikis/CSharpPlugin.wiki ]
At here, it gave me detail explanation for plugin, but every links or image are not available for now.

Is there any way to use Xcode for developing C#? Should I have to use MonoDevelop or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use a Mac for development so I would suggest you to use [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/) or [Rider from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). Both are very nice IDE's for C# on MacOS.